# Mysql - Group by multiple table and columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the two following tables:

```
 content:
 ========
 cid | iid | qty
 ---------------
   1 |   7 | 42
   2 |   7 |  1
   3 |   8 | 21

 ret:
 ====
 rid | cid | qty
 --------------
   1 |   1 |   2
   2 |   1 |  10
   3 |   2 |   1
```

I would like to retrieve, for each iid, the sum of `content.qty` and `ret.qty`
For exemple, for given tables, the result would be:

`iid=7, SUM(content.qty) = 43, SUM(ret.qty)=13`

`iid=8, SUM(content.qty) = 21, SUM(ret.qty)=0`

Is there any way to do it in one query?

In advance, thank you!

Comment: Why does `iid=7` have a `ret.qty` of 13?  What is the logic to total the `ret.qty`?

Comment: Which value in `content` ties to `ret`? It looks like it should be `cid` but that doesn't explain how `iid=7` has `SUM(ret.qty)=13`, nor does it explain the `ret.qty` sum for `iid=8`.

Comment: @bluefeet: `iid=7` have a `ret.qty` of 13 because all `rid` (1,2,3) refer to `cid` 1 and 2, which both refer to `iid=7`

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: it's the opposite. `cid` is the primary key of `content`, and many rows of `ret` could tie to `content`… in fact `ret.qty` sum for `iid=8` should be NULL because there is no row in `ret` which is tie to a row of content with an `iid=8`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, because you don't want duplicates in your sums.  To fix that problem, do the aggregations separately as subqueries.  The first is directly on `content` the second joins back to `content` from `ret` to get the `iid` column.

The following query follows this approach, and assumes that `cid` is a unique key on `content`:

```
select c.iid, c.qty + coalesce(r.qty, 0)
from (select c.iid, SUM(qty) as cqty
      from content c 
      group by c.iid
     ) c left outer join
     (select c.iid, SUM(r.qty) as rqty
      from ret r join
           content c
           on r.cid = c.cid
      group by c.iid
     ) r
     on c.iid = r.iid;
```